# python watchdog hang flask socketio

Tags: flask, flask-socketio, watchdog

I am using flask/flask socketio / rq. I need to run heavy tasks, so I am using rq.
Everything works fine.

the result of the task is a file and I want to track it changes. for that, I used a watchdog.
The problem is when I install watchdog socketio is not accepting incoming requests anymore.

what could be a problem? is usage watchdog is supported by socketio?

Comment: I assume you are using either eventlet or gevent? I'm not sure exactly what system calls watchdog makes, but they are surely blocking when used with these frameworks, so they will prevent the server from running. Maybe you can get things to work if you monkey patch the standard library.

Comment: Yeah, thanks, Miguel. I say many other post and monkey patch discussions. I am using a monkey patch. It doesn't help. 
Any other ideas? For the eventlet or geventI didn't configure the specific implementation, just a default .

Comment: You need to find a file monitoring method that is compatible with eventlet/gevent. No other way around that.

Comment: trying pyinotify, but a bit scary, the git repository quite long time and I am not sure about support for the future.

https://github.com/seb-m/pyinotify